# CommonJS modules in

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, commonjs, nrwl

Using Nx for my Angular workspace, and noticed something, which raised my question. What's the purpose to use CommonJS modules in all **tsconfig.spec.json** files for libs? Checking [Nx examples](https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples) all libs don't have it, only apps have included `"modules: "commonjs"`. Is it at all still needed, if in my case I'm working with modules purely on front-end side? Can't we rely on ES2015 (ES6) already in Angular/TypeScript projects for development? After all target is ES5 obviously, like so `"target": "es5"`.

Especially, if CommonJS modules are specific only for **tsconfig.spec.json** files, i.e. for unit testing (Jest in my case). Removing `"modules: "commonjs"` from my **tsconfig.spec.json** still makes all my unit tests passed, builded bundle is working fine, as well whilst checking during serving my application without any single error/warning.

Comment: Have you seen this ref before https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/external-modules.html?

Comment: Checked the [.tsconfig section](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/tsconfig.html) of this book, the author includes CommonJS there, but based on the Nx examples it confused me a bit. Especially, when generating a new Nx lib/project it includes CommonJS only in **tsconfig.spec.json** files, but all others are with ES2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing `"modules: "commonjs"`, and then adding a new lib realised that's really useful. Without this Jest doesn't compiles, so it's required for Jest. It could be also checked cleaning Jest's cache (`npx jest --clearCache`), and then trying to run it, it wouldn't compile.